# Outlook - rule to operate on exact email address

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, rules, email-filter

I'm trying to create a filter that moves all email from an email address like "supportGroup@mycompany.com" to a "support mail" folder. The problem is that in Outlook "supportGroup" is actually an email group, so my rule moves email from ANYone in that group to "support mail". Is it possible to have the rule only pick up emails that have a "from:" value of "supportGroup@myCompany.com" exactly?

Comment: Have you tried using the rules to look in the `header`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So it turns out there is a filter option I missed the first time around called "...with specific words in the sender's address". That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that `sender's address` does NOT match on the name - only the email address!
`John Doe <johndoe@somewhere.com>` can be matched as:

```
Apply to message
with "johndoe@somewhere.com" in the sender's address
  and with "From: John Doe <johndoe@somewhere.com>" in the message header
```

Comment: Your answer is unclear.

Comment: Please emphasis in what way unclear?! The example is a clip from Outlook rules.
I'm trying to point out that senders name is *not* a part of "sender's address", but can be matched in header.

Comment: It should be a comment. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Actually it does! The question is more complex than stated. From-address consists of both email address **and** name. If you do not distinguish between name and email you might end up in a mess (been there!)